# Select comma separated string depending on existing columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in my database which have a set of bit value columns. I want to insert a comma separated string in a new column, depending on the values of these bit columns.

Lets say the columns are named:

```
c1,c2,c3,c4
```

If the value in a column is equal to 1, I want to include the string mapped as following:

```
c1: 'campaign1'
c2: 'campaign2'
c3: 'campaign3'
c4: 'campaign4'
```

So for exampel, if a row contains the following values:

```
c1 = 1, c2 = 0, c3 = 1, c4 = 0
```

I want to insert the following in a new column named 'Campaigns'

```
'campaign1,campaign3'
```

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Keep in mind that delimited data in a column like that violates 1NF and is a serious PITA to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this using `stuff()` and some string manipulation:

```
select t.*,
       stuff( ((case when c1 = 1 then ',campaign1' else '' end) +
               (case when c2 = 1 then ',campaign2' else '' end) +
               (case when c3 = 1 then ',campaign3' else '' end) +
               (case when c4 = 1 then ',campaign4' else '' end)
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as campaigns
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it might not best the best solution:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (id INT, c1 INT, c2 INT, c3 INT, c4 INT);
INSERT INTO @table 
SELECT 1, 1, 0, 1, 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 0, 0, 1, 1;
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        CASE WHEN c1 = 1 THEN 'campaign1,' ELSE '' END + 
        CASE WHEN c2 = 1 THEN 'campaign2,' ELSE '' END + 
        CASE WHEN c3 = 1 THEN 'campaign3,' ELSE '' END + 
        CASE WHEN c4 = 1 THEN 'campaign4,' ELSE '' END AS campaigns
    FROM
        @table)
SELECT
    id,
    CASE 
        WHEN LEN(campaigns) > 0 THEN LEFT(campaigns, LEN(campaigns) - 1)
        ELSE ''
    END AS campaigns
FROM
    cte;
```

---

Gordon beat me to the `STUFF` method, which I was hastily writing when I realised this was better, but here's an answer that also shows how the `UPDATE` might work, as this is what you originally asked for:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (id INT, c1 INT, c2 INT, c3 INT, c4 INT, campaigns VARCHAR(512));
INSERT INTO @table 
SELECT 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, NULL;
UPDATE
    t
SET
    campaigns = STUFF(CASE WHEN c1 = 1 THEN ',campaign1' ELSE '' END + 
        CASE WHEN c2 = 1 THEN ',campaign2' ELSE '' END + 
        CASE WHEN c3 = 1 THEN ',campaign3' ELSE '' END + 
        CASE WHEN c4 = 1 THEN ',campaign4' ELSE '' END, 1, 1, '')
FROM
    @table t;

SELECT * FROM @table;
```

Results:

```
id  c1  c2  c3  c4  campaigns
1   1   0   1   0   campaign1,campaign3
2   0   0   1   1   campaign3,campaign4
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [IIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function ( provided you're using *SQL Server 2012+* ) as in the following :

```
select IIF(c1=1, 'Campaign1', '')+IIF(c2=1 and c1>0,',','')+
       IIF(c2=1, 'Campaign2', '')+IIF(c3=1 and c1+c2>0,',','')+
       IIF(c3=1, 'Campaign3', '')+IIF(c4=1 and c1+c2+c3>0,',','')+
       IIF(c4=1, 'Campaign4', '') as 'Campaigns'
  from tab t;
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/60025/2)

Answer (score 0):

Just to give another option, you can use concat and replace also

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (id INT, c1 INT, c2 INT, c3 INT, c4 INT)

INSERT INTO @table 
SELECT 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 UNION ALL SELECT 2, 0, 0, 1, 1

select t.*,
       replace(replace(c1, '1', 'Campaing1,'), '0', '') + 
       replace(replace(c2, '1', 'Campaing2,'), '0', '') + 
       replace(replace(c3, '1', 'Campaing3,'), '0', '') + 
       replace(replace(c4, '1', 'Campaing4,'), '0', '') 
from   @table t
```

The result is

```
id  c1  c2  c3  c4  COLUMN1 
--  --  --  --  --  ------- 
1   1   0   1   0   Campaing1,Campaing3,    
2   0   0   1   1   Campaing3,Campaing4,
```

But I would go for Gordon's answer